# Is it good style (or more efficient) to "return early" at the top of a function?

Tags: python

Sorry about the confusing title.

I recently started doing this in my project, and am wondering if it's more efficient, or not, and if it's a terrible style to practice.

Here's an example from a Database interface:

```
def register(self, user, pw):
    """Register user/pw into the database"""
    if self.isStarted():
        raise Exceptions.Started
    hashed = hashlib.sha512(pw).hexdigest()
    self._db_cur.execute('''INSERT INTO PLAYERS (name, password)
                                    values (?, ?)''', [user, hashed])
    self._db.commit()
```

I do it here with raising an exception, but I've done it in other places with a return.

I feel this allows the false-cases to exit the function at the top, instead of continuing down the function, seeing if there is any more code for them to run.

I rarely see this in code I look at: is this a bad practice, or does it not yield any performance like I imagine it to?

To help clarify, what I'm used to is:

```
if (somethingTrue):
    runThis()
    thisToo()
    x = andThis()
    return x
return None
```

and what I've started to do, and am iffy on:

```
if (!somethingTrue):
    return None
runThis()
thisToo()
x = andThis()
return x
```

The latter seems to give the impression (especially in functions longer than 4 lines) that the code isn't part of a conditional, when it's intended that way.  This also makes it look nicer, while adhering to PEP-8, so I'm really in a toss-up about it.

I have a feeling this breaks something horribly sacred.  Is this alright, or sacrilegious?

Comment: Do not worry about "efficiency" or "performance" here: *there is none to gain either way*. Write it the way that you (and your team) like best. The biggest thing is *to be consistent in your patterns*.

Comment: I have to admit I tend to prefer the second form (with early error checking and return), especially when the inside of the body is lengthy.  Having to track the extra indentation is one more thing to worry about and reading code is already hard enough as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One part of the question is about style and best practice - therefore IMHO is no 'correct' way.

In my opinion the nested version (no direct return) comes from 'historic' programming languages like 'C' where the whole cleanup is done once at the right place. Artificial example to show the point only:

```
int f() {
   int result = 1;
   char * buffer = (char *)malloc(77);
   if(buffer!=NULL) {
      int const fd = open("/tmp/data.log", O_RDONLY);
      if(fd!=-1) {
         ssize_t const read_cnt = read(fd, buffer, 77);
         if(read_cnt!=77) {
            /* Do something: was not possible to read 77 bytes. */
            result = 0;
         }
         close(fd);
      }
      free(buffer);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Here it is not correct to return from other lines than the last one - because then there might be a resource leak.

When using only objects which are destroyed completely in their destructor - or when there is no need to clean up resources (because none were allocated), I prefer the 'short' path return.  This make things clearer like: if the preconditions for a function is not meet, there is no way to 'really' execute the function body. Also: you don't need that much indentation and it is easier to read.

Performance: I made some tests; I was not able to measure a difference between the two ways.  IMHO if you need to tune performance at this level, you might want to think about choosing another programming language. ;-)

Comment: I've been wondering why it's always been done the more stoic way, thanks!  
Thank you for doing performance tests, I had no idea where to begin trying it, and if it was even a common practice.  It definitely makes the code cleaner!  And I don't necessarily need to squeeze that much microperformance out of the code, but I was using this step as a learning catalyst, incase I ever see the problem on a much larger scale.    Good to know that I'm not dealing with a coding faux pax, and where the stoic method came from!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you must do the check anyway (for correctness), then I think it's a fine idea to do it at the top.

There are cases where you can choose (1) to do a check to avoid unnecessary work, or (2) just skip the check and always do the work. In such cases, you might consider skipping the check if you think the not-doing-the-work case will be rare enough that the extra checks will cost more than doing unnecessary work from time to time (profile if you really want to be sure). Then again, it might not be clear which is the case; then I'd say a simple if statement is pretty cheap (assuming the check itself isn't expensive), so just do the check and don't worry too much unless you see performance problems. You can always do profiling later.

**Edit**: Based on your further example, it sounds like you had a different issue in mind. On that subject, I'd say you should generally put the case with the shortest code first, so you don't have something like

```
if positive_case:
  lots of stuff
  lots more stuff
  ...
else:
  whatever this corresponds to is now off the screen
```

Your technique is also a common way to avoid too much nesting. By exiting from the `if`, and leaving out the `else`, you can flatten

```
if error:
  raise exception
else:
  do more stuff
  if error:
    ...
```

to

```
if error:
  raise exception

do more stuff
if error:
  ...
```

I think as you alluded, PEP-8 actually mentions and recommends this technique. I'm not sure why you feel this might be sacrilegious. Many things are just personal preference, with pros and cons either way, and you're entitled to your own opinion on the tradeoffs.

Comment: Thanks!  I like the idea of having the shortest conditions towards the top, and the conditionals doing the work more in the body.

I didn't know it was a common practice.  Guess I've been looking at the long code for a while :)

I mentioned PEP-8 for the 79 characters-per-line aspect, I didn't know this was considered the recommended technique.  

Thank you very much!